# Kotlin check connection in BaseActivity

Tags: android, kotlin

I have created function to check internet connection in my `BaseActivity` file but it does not work (redirect user)

#### Code

> Code is commented for better understanding

`BaseActivity.kt`

```
open class BaseActivity: AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var prefManager: PrefManager

    override fun attachBaseContext(newBase: Context) {
        // my app languages codes...
        super.attachBaseContext(localeUpdatedContext)


        // check internet connection
        // What I'm trying to do here is to redirect user into specific activity when connection is lost (it would be best if we can run it every minute or so.)
        if(!isNetworkAvailable()) {
            val intent = Intent(newBase, NoInternetActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
            finish()
        }
    }

    // internet connection function
    fun  isNetworkAvailable() : Boolean{
        val conManager = getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
        val internetInfo =conManager.activeNetworkInfo
        return internetInfo!=null && internetInfo.isConnected
    }

    class ContextUtils(base: Context) : ContextWrapper(base) {
        companion object {
            // my other codes...
        }
    }

    open fun openDialog() {}
}
```

**Any suggestions?**

## Update

I've made following changes which results in redirecting user to next activity if connection is lost but as it is working with Task Timer it refreshes next activity constantly I need it to redirect only once

```
open class BaseActivity: AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun attachBaseContext(newBase: Context) {
        // my app languages codes...
        super.attachBaseContext(localeUpdatedContext)

        // check connection every 5 seconds
        val timer = Timer()
        val MILLISECONDS = 5000 //5 seconds
        val timerr = timer.schedule(CheckConnection(this), 0, MILLISECONDS.toLong())
        Log.d("CheckConnection", timerr.toString())
    }

    internal class CheckConnection(private val context: Context) : TimerTask() {
        fun isNetworkAvailable(context: Context): Boolean {
            val connectivityManager = context.getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
            val activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.activeNetworkInfo
            return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected
        }

        override fun run() {
            if (!isNetworkAvailable(context)) {
                Log.d("CheckConnection", "DISCONNECTED")
                val intent = Intent(context, NoInternetActivity::class.java)
                context.startActivity(intent)
            } else {
                Log.d("CheckConnection", "CONNECTED")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

PS: I've tried to use `finish()` after my intent `startActivity` but I got `Unresolved reference: finish`

Comment: `finish()` should be used before calling `startActivity` because if the other activity is started that means first activity context is destroyed. Also, since you are doing this timer thing, the run will execute every 5 mins. You can either use a single event approach or you can check if the current activity is the timeout page, then you don't need to execute the code inside if condition in the run function.

Comment: @MohitAjwani would you mind show me how? in an answer? because I have no idea how to do what you suggested :/

Comment: @MohitAjwani I guess not!

Comment: you should just make sure that `internetInfo!=null && internetInfo.isConnected` actually checks if you _do_ have a connection, i think this will just check if you're connected to a network and it won't really guarentee that the network has internet access. usually people ping google (or some server) to see if there's internet or not, but maybe this works for what you want

Comment: @a_local_nobody about pinging google I am aware of that for for now first I need to make this timer work then I will change my code to check google etc.